# Delete button in calculator

Tags: android, calculator

I'm creating a calculator, I made a delete button but when I run the app, it crashes and stops.
This is my java code:

Help me please.

```
       private static String removeLastChar(String str) {
       return str.substring(0,str.length()-1);
```

and this

```
        bdelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            editText.setText(removeLastChar(editText.getText().toString()));
        }
       });
```

here's my log

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   ComponentInfo{player.android.com.layout/player.android.com.layout.MyActivity}:  java.lang.NullPointerException
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
         at player.android.com.layout.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:68)
         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Where is your Logcat????

Comment: show your MyActivity.java:68?

Comment: prakash here is MyActivity.java:68

bdelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                editText.setText(removeLastChar(editText.getText().toString()));
            }
        });

Comment: yes i have initialized EditText  as eddittext

Answer (score 2):

```
This is late but help someone.....

delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String s=editText.getText().toString();
        s=s.substring(0,s.lenght()-1)
        editText.setText(s);
    }
   });

this helps for deleting last digit from editText.
i also refer this from
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21893558/what-is-the-best-way-to-delete-the-last-digit-in-a-calculator-app
```

Answer (score 1):

With this code you will remove all characters , because you say remove from 0 to length-1 characters .

```
str.substring(0,str.length()-1);
```

For example:

String ll = "Lorem Ipsum is simply"

if you say `String ii = ll.substring(0,2);`

you'll get : `ii == "Lor"`.

**Try something like this:**

```
   public String remove(){
        String character = "2313213";
        String character1 = "";
        for(int i=0;i<character.length()-1;i++){
            character1 += character.charAt(i);
        }

        return character1;
    }
```

Comment: I just want to remove 1 char 
i have made a clear button now just want a delete button to delete 1 last char only

Comment: ok where to put thsi code ?

str.substring(0,str.length()-1);

or just have to put this 

  public String remove(){
        String character = "2313213";
        String character1 = "";
        for(int i=0;i<character.length()-1;i++){
            character1 += character.charAt(i);
        }

        return character1;
    }

Comment: Put my code "remove" or substring(str.length()-1 , str.length());

Comment: error is in this line 

bdelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

Comment: try this: editText.setText(removeLastChar(editText.getText().toString()) + "");

Comment: error occured 


java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
            at player.android.com.layout.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:68)